# Rails SQL : How to search for records with a list of combination values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I want to search a table for a list of pair values. 
Ex. This is an array of first and last names.

```
array = [['jane','doe'],['jack','chen'],['jane','ty'],['mike','ji'],['mike','smith']]
```

I want to search the User table for each one of these combinations. 
Currently, I can only think of running a query per combination.

```
array.each do |a|
 User.where("firstname like (?) and lastname like (?)",a[0],a[1])
end
```

Is there any way of running all the queries in a single query?
Maintaining the combinations is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work for you

```
query_string_array = []
query_array = []
array.each do |a|
 query_string_array << "(firstname like '%?%' AND lastname like '%?%')"
 query_array << a
end

User.where(query_string_array.join(" OR "), *query_array.flatten)
```

Comment: Thank you Salil. This is very useful